# Autoload dependencies in Laravel 5.2 package development

Tags: php, package, laravel-5, autoload

I'm developing a Laravel 5.2 Package and I have the same problem described in [#30996765](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996765/laravel-5-1-package-development-loading-packages-dependencies-in-development):

The dependencies required in composer.json are not loaded by default, so I tried the method suggested in the question above, manually including the autoload file in the Service Provider class:

```
public function boot()
{
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php'; 
}
```

It works for the package dependencies, but it seems that the main autoload (the one created by composer in Laravel base dir) is overwritten by the package one, so all the basic Laravel classes (like Response) are no more available.

Do you have any suggestion to resolve this issue?